Globally catch warnings and errors RShiny
How to globally catch warnings and errors in a RShiny application (without using a tryCatch in every function/ observeEvent or withCallingHandlers?
E.g. the next code sample does not seem to work:
options(warning.expression = {
    last_warnings <- getOption("last.warning")
    if (length(last_warnings) > 0) {
      new_warning <- conditionMessage(last_warnings[[1]])
      # Append the warning to the reactive value
      warnings(c(warnings(), new_warning))
      # Print the warning message to the console - DOSOMETHING
      cat("Warning:", new_warning, "\n")
    }
  })

last.warnings remains NULL.
and
options(warning.expression = quote({ 
  warning_message <- conditionMessage(warning()) 
  print_to_output(warning_message) 
})

results in "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"

Please see this related question.
